# Why does the non-capturing group change the behaviour of the regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am compiling a regex patter to match specific commands in a debug console, one of them is:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$");
```

so it is possible to enter

```
\connect 127.0.0.1 2345
```

or leave the port

```
\connect 127.0.0.1
```

spaces are ignored as long as I use at last one space to separate the fields.

It works perfectly, however, while the ip goes to group 1 (which is ok), the port goes to group 3 (as written, I know).

So I wanted to use an non-capturing group for the first three parts of the ip address:

```
Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$");
```

So I thought I would get the ip in group 1 and the port in group 2.
But now the Matcher.matches() returns false for the same input... Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wild guess: The problem is somewhere else.
I did a quick test:

```
        String test = "\\connect 127.0.0.1 2345";
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$");
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$");

    System.out.println(p1.matcher(test).matches());
    System.out.println(p2.matcher(test).matches());
```

Output:
true
true

Comment: Arrgh, it is indeed working. First I had a other problem resulting in the false of the Matcher. I fixed this together with removing the ?: so it worked again. Then I retried the non-grouping but with the breakpoint _behind_ the matcher.group(2) calls. It wasn't hit, so I thought it is still not working. But the problem was that I forgot to change the call for group containing the port from 3 to 2. So there was an exception. I couldn't see it, because it was catched without output in the try catch construction around a Method.invoke call which invokes a method calling the command check method.

Answer (score 0):

```
"^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$"
```

I tried it in Eclipse IDE Search/Replace and it finds the `\connect 3.54.1.4 4234` String and nicely replaces `\1` with the ip and `\2` with the port.

This also returns true:

```
"\\connect 3.54.1.4 4234".matches("^\\s*\\\\connect\\s+((?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3})(?:\\s+(\\d+))?\\s*$");
```